# pl/sql part not executing when script is run from a cronjob

Tags: linux, oracle, cron

I have a script in which I connect as sysdba and run a query.The script works perfectly fine when I run it standalone by sh command.But when I run the script from a cronjob the script runs but the sql part is omitted .

My script is like

```
echo "before connection"
sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF

Select * from dual
EOF
```

It works perfectly fine when I run by:

```
   sh script_name.sh
```

But When I run by a cronjob the connection part is omitted only line which I get in my logs in "before connection"

What could be the solution of this problem?

Comment: @LalitKumarB No I didn't try the silent option of sqlplus.Moreover, the result of the queries is redirected to a text file and after the cronjob is run, the text file is found to be empty.

Comment: Then probably you need to set the environment variables properly. If `sqlplus` is not being invoked, then make sure you have exported the `PATH` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you get the error `sqlplus not found`. When run from crontab.

You have to export your `PATH` variable in the script explicitly. Else, load the .profile itself, if needed. Because, your `crontab` just executes the script, without defining the variables that you had in your `.profile`.

Add this to your script, to always load your .profile

```
. $HOME/.profile
```

OR

```
. ~/.profile
```

Comment: I used your solution but the sql part of the script is still not running.

Comment: @user2262977 echo your `$PATH` variable, and check what is in it. And also you can try to give the abosule path for `sqlplus` .. `ex: /oracle/home/bin/sqlplus /  as sysdba...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on UNIX (UNIX-like) systems, `shebang` is mandatory. Have you tried `shebang` on the first line ? (`bash` is the shell of choice in my systems)

```
#!/bin/bash
```

More explanation [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=execve&sektion=2).

Comment: I had used the shebang also but the ql part is not running.